# count line with highest character in a paragraph

Tags: php

i have a string which has 5-10 lines and i want to count the no of character in longest line.

i know with strlen or mb_str we can count the length of string but i want output of highest line only.
for example this is the string

```
 1k Ladke ne dekha to 
puchaki kea hua??
Purana Calender hai, Hawa se padhpadha raha hai........ 
Buddha bola :- Kuch nehi beta
```

i want the no of character of third line so output will be 55 character.
 i think i should start for loop and use strlen to count the character in each line and output but how the final output will be longest one. for loop will give last or first output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$str = '1k Ladke ne dekha to\npuchaki kea hua??\n
Purana Calender hai, Hawa se padhpadha raha hai........\n
Buddha bola :- Kuch nehi beta';

$array = explode('\n', $str);
$maxlen = max(array_map('strlen', $array));
print_r($maxlen);
```

Comment: how we can do for hindi character. strlen will count byte instead of character